# This Ember belongsTo relationship is working, but I can't see how

Tags: json, ember.js, relationships

I've been developing an app for about a year now, so I started it mid-2014 and have been upgrading ember.js and ember-cli as things move forward on those projects. I'm at Ember 1.11 now.

**EDIT: Application Adapter**

```
var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend( {
  namespace: 'api',
  host: null,
  setHost: Ember.on('init', function() {
    set(this, 'host', this.container._registry.resolve('config:environment').API_ENDPOINT);
  })

});

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

My JSON API returns a main `projects` object, along with other sideloaded objects (like projectStatus). What I can't understand is, since I don't have any adapters or serializers that specify this, how I'm it's able to use the returned JSON, because it looks like this:

```
{
  "projects" : {
    "id": 4462875
    "projectName" : "New business from Acme",
    "projectDescription" : "Just another great project",
    "pmlinks" : [ 1, 2],
    "statusLinks" : [ 1440 ],
    "commentsLinks" : [ 39 ]
  },
  "projectResources" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Wile E. Coyote"
  }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Roadrunner"
  }],
  "projectComments" : [ {
    "id" : 39,
    "projectComment" : "started the project",
  } ],
  "projectStatuses" : [ {
    "id" : 1440,
    "status" : "G",
    "trending" : "N",
    "comment" : null,
    "lastModifiedDate" : "2015-07-17T13:46:11.037+0000",
    "project" : 4462875
  } ],
}
```

I can't find anything in the [Ember docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships) that recommend this "*Links" format for the relationships, and in fact it suggests using something more like `status_ids`. But the example it shows *doesn't* use `_ids` so I'm even more confused.

Here's a snippet of my project model:

```
statusUpdates: DS.hasMany('projectStatus'),
projectComments: DS.hasMany('projectComment'),
projectResources: DS.hasMany('projectResource'),
```

What I'm trying to figure out is with my new belongsTo relationship to `schedule`, how should the JSON be formatted from the API? It seems to work if the project object has a property like this `"scheduleLinks": [10]` but **not** if it's like `"schedule": 10` or `"schedule_id": 10` and that seems to be what the documentation says should work.

**EDIT:**
Maybe it's because the other objects like projectComments are named the way my model expects, and they're all returned at the same time from one API, that it doesn't even matter what the properties in the projects object is? Is that only to look up relationships if they're not all sideloaded?

Comment: Is it `pmlinks` or `pmLinks`?

Comment: @torazaburo it actually is `pmlinks` which only furthers my suspicions that the property really isn't doing a thing in my application. Which therefore leads me to wonder what I'm missing conceptually since I don't understand why I'd even need a property to reference the IDs of the other relationships if it's not using them for anything.

Answer (score 0):

The sideloading definitely is the thing here. Because if I change "statusLinks" to "projectStatus" then, since I have that relationship established in the `project` model, it will try to hit the API for that, e.g. `/api/projectstatuses/:id`.

So what seems to be happening is that the relationship is being hooked up from the belongsTo side implicitly; if the data is sideloaded, I don't need any links or IDs on the main object.